# How can I recreate a graph paper grid in Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, grids

In Photoshop we can display the grid, but I want this grid to be printed so I want to make the grid myself. What's an easy way to make this?

[image]

Comment: Do you want this grid at specific distance or just grid lines and do you need that grid style too, which has dark line with 3 grey lines in between?

Answer (score 6):

Filter > Vanishing Point...

Set the grid size to the increments you want then double-click the Grid tool.

[image: grid]

Then with the little preferences menu there at the top left be certain to select "Render Grids to Photoshop".

[image: render grids]

And then just click OK.

You'll get a grid on the document as a pixel layer. You can then change color or desaturate to get rid of the blue.

[image: grid]

If you want the varying line weights and dotted lines, there is no easy method with Photoshop. You could however set something up in Illustrator then copy/paste to Photoshop as a Smart Object.

Edit: You can get a grid with darker major divisions by making a second grid with a Grid Size equal to some multiple of the first one (e.g. 4 to make one like in the original post).  Save it to a different layer, then use layer properties (for example) to make the stroke wider or change the color.

Comment: at least which version needed for this?

Comment: Any version with the Vanishing Point Filter. I don't know when that was specifically introduced, but it's been around for several versions. At least it's present in all version which will run on my machine CS3+ (v10+).

Comment: ok - but render grid to photoshop is greyed out and I cannot find any way to activate it!

Comment: Once you double click on the "Grid tool" do not deselect the grid or click anything else. Go straight to the drop down box to select "Render Grids to Photoshop" and then hit OK on the top right.

Answer (score 3):

**Creating Graph with Pattern**

1. Take a document size of 1 inch by 1 inch. With line tool create a line horizontally the select with the **Path Selection Tool** and **Shift+Alt+Down Arrow** Keys 8 times to create total 9 lines.
2. Take top line and align to top and bottom line to bottom of the document with help of align panel.
3. Select all lines and Distribute Heights.
4. While selected change line color to light grey.

[image]

5. **Crtl+J** to duplicate layer, change it's color to Black.
6. Select middle line and transform **(Ctrl+T)** and change height to 200%
7. Delete 3 lines between Top, Middle and bottom.
8. Select both layer and Duplicate then **Ctrl+T)** and rotate 90 degree.
9. Move both Black layers above grey layers.

It will look something like this.

[image]

10. Remove background layer.
11. Go to **Menu -> Edit-> Define Pattern** and save pattern as Graph
12. Create new document and **Edit->Fill** or **(Shift+F5)** to bring fill dialog box, select pattern and OK. If you like to change color of the the pattern then fill pattern on a new layer and apply layer style.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

With photoshop open and a document displayed the size paper you want, go to your snipping tool (not Photoshop, program that comes with Windows I think).  Draw around the document, click copy and then in PS on a new layer hit paste.  Take off "view grid"

Answer (score 0):

1) Measure the width of your grid eg: 1024 px

2) Divide it by the number of grids you want eg: 10 grids >> 1024/10 = 102.4

3) Create a new document with width and height as 102 Px

4) Select the Rectangle marquee tool and just select the insides of the 102 
pixel document ( minimal width will do better) and then go to SELECT>INVERSE

5) Now goto Edit>Fill>Select Black from drop down menu and click OK

6) Now select Background from layers, then select the magic eraser tool from sub selection of eraser and click on the white part. The background erases and only the black border line remains.

7) Now goto edit>Define Pattern and save your pattern in some name say" 102Grid"

8) Now open your reference Image and goto Edit>Fill , select pattern from drop down and choose your custom pattern and click okey.

9) Thats it.. You will have your picture with the 102 pixel grid. Save or print for your Needs :)